# Installation errors with old version of mod_perl (2.0.3) with Apache 2.2.25 on Debian10

Tags: c, perl, apache2, mod-perl

I am trying to mirror the Ensembl using these instructions:
https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/webcode/mirror/install/non-ensembl-code.html#apache

They recommend specific versions of mod_perl and Apache2. My system is an AWS Debian 10 instance.

I can successfully install Apache2, but when issuing the following commands, I get errors in what appears to be the compilation of mod_perl from source.

```
sudo apt install git
git --version
sudo apt install gnupg
cd /tmp; wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.20-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config*
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo systemctl status mysql

#if you need C compiler & zlib development lib
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev/oldstable

#Apache2 install instructions and where to DL mod_perl
cd /tmp; wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/perl/mod_perl-2.0.3.tar.gz
tar zxf httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz
tar zxf mod_perl-2.0.3.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.2.25
#PREFIX will default to /usr/local/apache2 if not specified
./configure \
--enable-deflate \
--enable-headers \
--enable-expires \
--enable-rewrite \
--enable-proxy \
--enable-proxy-http \
--enable-unique-id;
cd ../mod_perl-2.0.3
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/usr/local/apache2/ MP_APXS=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs/

make
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
cd "src/modules/perl" && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/mod_perl-2.0.3/src/modules/perl'
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -I/tmp/mod_perl-2.0.3/src/modules/perl -I/tmp/mod_perl-2.0.3/xs -I/usr/local/apache2/include -I/usr/local/apache2/include  -I/usr/local/apache2/include -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28/CORE -DMOD_PERL -DMP_COMPAT_1X -DLINUX -O2 -g -fPIC \
-c mod_perl.c &&  mod_perl.o mod_perl.lo
In file included from mod_perl.h:95,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_debug.h:23:17: warning: inline function ‘modperl_pid_tid’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE char *modperl_pid_tid(apr_pool_t *p);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from mod_perl.h:91,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_cgi.h:35:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_cgi_header_parse’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE int modperl_cgi_header_parse(request_rec *r, char *buffer,
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from mod_perl.h:85,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_filter.h:105:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_input_filter_write’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_status_t modperl_input_filter_write(pTHX_
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:100:22: warning: inline function ‘modperl_input_filter_read’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_size_t modperl_input_filter_read(pTHX_
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:82:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_output_filter_write’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_status_t modperl_output_filter_write(pTHX_
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:77:22: warning: inline function ‘modperl_output_filter_read’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_size_t modperl_output_filter_read(pTHX_
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:74:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_input_filter_flush’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_status_t modperl_input_filter_flush(modperl_filter_t *filter);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:73:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_output_filter_flush’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_status_t modperl_output_filter_flush(modperl_filter_t *filter);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:44:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_wbucket_write’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_status_t modperl_wbucket_write(pTHX_
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:41:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_wbucket_flush’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_status_t modperl_wbucket_flush(modperl_wbucket_t *b,
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_filter.h:37:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_wbucket_pass’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE apr_status_t modperl_wbucket_pass(modperl_wbucket_t *b,
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from mod_perl.h:83,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_io.h:60:16: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_perlio_restore_stdout’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void modperl_io_perlio_restore_stdout(pTHX_ GV *handle);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:58:16: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_perlio_restore_stdin’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void modperl_io_perlio_restore_stdin(pTHX_ GV *handle);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:56:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_perlio_override_stdout’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE GV *modperl_io_perlio_override_stdout(pTHX_ request_rec *r);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:54:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_perlio_override_stdin’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE GV *modperl_io_perlio_override_stdin(pTHX_ request_rec *r);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:52:16: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_handle_untie’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void modperl_io_handle_untie(pTHX_ GV *handle);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:50:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_handle_tied’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE int modperl_io_handle_tied(pTHX_ GV *handle, char *classname);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:48:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_tie_stdin’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE GV *modperl_io_tie_stdin(pTHX_ request_rec *r);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:46:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_tie_stdout’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE GV *modperl_io_tie_stdout(pTHX_ request_rec *r);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io.h:44:16: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_handle_tie’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void modperl_io_handle_tie(pTHX_ GV *handle,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from modperl_io.h:20,
                 from mod_perl.h:83,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_io_apache.h:57:19: warning: inline function ‘modperl_request_read’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE SSize_t modperl_request_read(pTHX_ request_rec *r,
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_io_apache.h:37:16: warning: inline function ‘modperl_io_apache_init’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void modperl_io_apache_init(pTHX);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from mod_perl.h:76,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_handler.h:47:23: warning: inline function ‘modperl_handler_name’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE const char *modperl_handler_name(modperl_handler_t *handler);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_handler.h:29:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_handler_anon_get’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE CV *modperl_handler_anon_get(pTHX_ modperl_mgv_t *anon);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_handler.h:28:16: warning: inline function ‘modperl_handler_anon_add’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void modperl_handler_anon_add(pTHX_ modperl_mgv_t *anon, CV *cv);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_handler.h:27:26: warning: inline function ‘modperl_handler_anon_next’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE modperl_mgv_t *modperl_handler_anon_next(pTHX_ apr_pool_t *p);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from mod_perl.h:73,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_util.h:88:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_perl_module_loaded’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE int modperl_perl_module_loaded(pTHX_ const char *name);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_util.h:82:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_dir_config’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE SV *modperl_dir_config(pTHX_ request_rec *r, server_rec *s,
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_util.h:64:16: warning: inline function ‘modperl_perl_av_push_elts_ref’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void modperl_perl_av_push_elts_ref(pTHX_ AV *dst, AV *src);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_util.h:47:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_ptr2obj’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE SV *modperl_ptr2obj(pTHX_ char *classname, void *ptr);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_util.h:45:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_newSVsv_obj’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE SV *modperl_newSVsv_obj(pTHX_ SV *stashsv, SV *obj);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_util.h:41:24: warning: inline function ‘modperl_sv2request_rec’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE request_rec *modperl_sv2request_rec(pTHX_ SV *sv);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_util.h:40:23: warning: inline function ‘modperl_sv2server_rec’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE server_rec *modperl_sv2server_rec(pTHX_ SV *sv);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from modperl_util.h:20,
                 from mod_perl.h:73,
                 from mod_perl.c:17:
modperl_common_util.h:97:26: warning: inline function ‘modperl_uri_new’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE modperl_uri_t *modperl_uri_new(apr_pool_t *p);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_common_util.h:94:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_perl_sv_setref_uv’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE SV *modperl_perl_sv_setref_uv(pTHX_ SV *rv,
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_common_util.h:91:17: warning: inline function ‘modperl_hash_tied_object’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE void *modperl_hash_tied_object(pTHX_ const char *classname,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_common_util.h:87:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_hash_tied_object_rv’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE SV *modperl_hash_tied_object_rv(pTHX_
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
modperl_common_util.h:83:15: warning: inline function ‘modperl_hash_tie’ declared but never defined
 MP_INLINE SV *modperl_hash_tie(pTHX_ const char *classname,
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/bin/sh: 2: mod_perl.o: not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:112: mod_perl.lo] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/mod_perl-2.0.3/src/modules/perl'
make: *** [Makefile:453: modperl_lib] Error 2
```

I am not very skilled with Perl or C, but I think it is wrapping the compiling process. I do not know if the inline function warnings are important. I do know that the final (3) lines are important.
Has anyone seen such an error with mod_perl, or can someone explain what I might want to check next?

Thanks for looking at the problem!

Comment: The warnings are harmless. The declaration suggests that the functions should be inlined for better performance, and the compiler is advising that it can't. So, the entirety of the relevant error message is `/bin/sh: 2: mod_perl.o: not found`

Comment: Why are you doing: `tar zxf httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz` but then doing: `cd httpd-2.2.4`? Shouldn't the revs match?

Comment: You risk negative feedback, if you do not make more obvious what is C about this.

Comment: @Craig Estey - I rechecked the directory & updated the pasted code. I had previously been testing with another version. The correct directory name is httpd-2.2.25 .

Comment: @Yunnosch I am aware that the "inline function" warnings are issues with the C code used in the compiling process. It sounds like they are not important. I am looking into the Perl script and it looks like it utilizes Apache2::Build (https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::Build). I do not know how the Apache2::Build methods work internally to compile the Apache2 source from C, but that is the connection.

Comment: I'm using fedora 29, so I'm having trouble building mod_perl with these instructions (after some hacks). But, my system has mod_perl 2.0.11 already installed and fc29 is _ancient_ (years old). So, going back to mod_perl 2.0.3 is probably problematic (e.g. in later versions, the warnings would probably be fixed). The doc does _not_ mandate 2.0.3 To me, it's like that was the latest version available at the time the doc was written and the the doc was never updated. So, I'd _skip_ the rebuild of apache/mod_perl and just use the standard install

Comment: Just start with ensembl install. I'd fix/patch ensembl rather than going back to ancient apache/mod_perl. That _should_ be relatively minor. Only if there is some _massive_ incompatibility, would I revert apache/mod_perl. And, there _shouldn't_ be: mod_perl 2.0.11 (e.g.) should be backwards compatible with 2.0.3 (otherwise, we'd need a more major rev change (e.g.) 2.1.0 or 3.0.0). And, maybe ensembl doesn't need the full source but only the `*-dev` packages installed.

Comment: If you must rebuild apache/mod_perl from source, I'd pull the source package via `apt-get` from your distro rather than the website. All this version matching between apps/packages is what distros do best.